# setTimout method not working not exucting as many times as it should

Tags: javascript, settimeout, dijkstra

I am trying to create a cool little visual of how Dijkstra's algorithm works on a grid. The user is supposed to click on two tiles and then it should show you all the tiles that have been searched. At this point, I have been able to successfully paint all the tiles that are searched but I now want to turn it into an animation rather than the program painting all the tiles at once at the end. The issue is when I use the setTimout method it only seems to paint 4 tiles regardless of the distance between the two points and it completely ignores most of the other setTimout calls. Here is the image of the grid.

[Image before setTimeouts are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRfq6.png)
[Image after setTimeouts are added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvET4.png)

Here is the majority of my code excluding some helper functions and the drawgrid function that creates the grid and includes the call to handleClick function.

Feeds the Dijkstra function with starting and end coordinates

```js
function handleClick(event) {
    let xPos = event.offsetX;
    let yPos = event.offsetY;
    let col = Math.floor(xPos / colWidth);
    let row = Math.floor(yPos / colWidth);

    if (selectingStart) {
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 255, 0)";
        context.fillRect(col * colWidth, row * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
        startNode = createCoordinate(col, row);
        selectingStart = false;
    } else if (selectingEnd) {
        context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 0, 0)";
        context.fillRect(col * colWidth, row * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
        endNode = createCoordinate(col, row);
        selectingEnd = false;

        dijkstra(startNode, endNode);
        canvas.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    }
}
```

Creates left, right, top, and bottom tiles and checks to see if they are the end coordinate. After the tile is checked it will be painted blue.

Currently, I am setting the timeout methods around the tile painting logic. I tried also wrapping it around the if statements but then I would get an error saying that coordinate[0] was undefined.

```js
function dijkstra(startCoordinate, endCoordinate) {
    let pathFound = false;
    let coordinates = [];
    coordinates.push(startCoordinate);
    let timer = 0;

    while (coordinates.length > 0) {

        if (coordinates[0] === endCoordinate) {
            console.log("ENOUGH")
            return true;
        }
        let leftTile = createCoordinate(coordinates[0].xPos - 1, coordinates[0].yPos);
        let rightTile = createCoordinate(coordinates[0].xPos + 1, coordinates[0].yPos);
        let bottomTile = createCoordinate(coordinates[0].xPos, coordinates[0].yPos - 1);
        let topTile = createCoordinate(coordinates[0].xPos, coordinates[0].yPos + 1);

        if (coordinates[0].xPos > 0 && !visitedNodes.has(stringifyCoordinate(leftTile))) {
            if (compareCoordinates(leftTile, endCoordinate)) {
                console.log("ENOUGH")
                return true;
            }

            coordinates.push(leftTile);
            timer++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
                context.fillRect((coordinates[0].xPos - 1) * colWidth, coordinates[0].yPos * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
            }, 0 + timer * 0)

        }
        if (coordinates[0].xPos < (canvasWidth / colWidth) && !visitedNodes.has(stringifyCoordinate(rightTile))) {
            if (compareCoordinates(rightTile, endCoordinate)) {
                console.log("ENOUGH")
                return true;
            }

            coordinates.push(rightTile);
            timer++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
                context.fillRect((coordinates[0].xPos + 1) * colWidth, coordinates[0].yPos * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
            }, 0 + timer * 0)
            // alert("FILL");
        }
        if (coordinates[0].yPos > 0 && !visitedNodes.has(stringifyCoordinate(bottomTile))) {
            if (compareCoordinates(bottomTile, endCoordinate)) {
                console.log("ENOUGH")
                return true;
            }

            coordinates.push(bottomTile);
            timer++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
                context.fillRect(coordinates[0].xPos * colWidth, (coordinates[0].yPos - 1) * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
            }, 0 + timer * 0)
        }
        if (coordinates[0].yPos < (canvasWidth / colWidth) && !visitedNodes.has(stringifyCoordinate(topTile))) {
            if (compareCoordinates(topTile, endCoordinate)) {
                console.log("ENOUGH")
                return true;
            }

            coordinates.push(topTile);
            timer++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                context.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
                context.fillRect(coordinates[0].xPos * colWidth, (coordinates[0].yPos + 1) * colWidth, 49.5, 49.5);
            }, 0 + timer * 0)
        }
        visitedNodes.add(stringifyCoordinate(coordinates[0]));
        coordinates.shift();
    }
}
```

`drawGrid()`

I appreciate the help.

Comment: `0 + timer * 0` is not a very long delay, even if it was a unit larger than millis.

Comment: Yeah I was originally thinking the timing was causing the issue so I set all the delays to 0 but faced the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that by the time the `setTimeout` callback executes, the whole Dijkstra algorithm has already finished, and `coordinates` has mutated. This happens because `dijkstra` is running synchronously, and asynchronous tasks can only execute when JavaScript's call stack is empty, so after `dijkstra` has returned. At that time `coordinates[0]` is no longer the point you expected, but is the entry from which the target was eventually found and `dijkstra` could return.

If you want to use `setTimeout` like that, you must make sure the callback accesses variables that are *reserved* for that purpose so that they will not be altered before the callback gets to execute. You can do that with a local (block scoped) variable -- instead of `coordinates` which keeps on mutating throughout the algorithm.

I would also suggest to avoid that code repetition you have. The cases for left, top, right, bottom are almost the same, so this can better be done in a single code block and a loop over these four directions.

And obviously you should use a timeout value that is more significant (not 0), like 100 milliseconds per tick.

Here is a modification of your `dijkstra` function that will do it:

```js
function dijkstra(startCoordinate, endCoordinate) {
    if (compareCoordinates(startCoordinate, endCoordinate)) { // Trivial case
        fillTile(endCoordinate, "rgb(255, 255, 0)")
        return true;
    }
    const coordinates = [];
    coordinates.push(startCoordinate);
    visitedNodes.add(stringifyCoordinate(startCoordinate));
    let timer = 0;

    while (coordinates.length > 0) {
        const tile = coordinates.shift();
        // Avoid code repetition: use loop for the four directions
        for (const [dx, dy] of [[-1, 0], [0, -1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]) {
            const neighbor = createCoordinate(tile.xPos + dx, tile.yPos + dy);
            if (!validCoordinate(neighbor) || visitedNodes.has(stringifyCoordinate(neighbor))) continue;
            visitedNodes.add(stringifyCoordinate(neighbor));
            coordinates.push(neighbor);
            timer++;
            const found = compareCoordinates(neighbor, endCoordinate);
            setTimeout(function () {
                // neighbor is a variable that will not have been mutated.
                // Maybe use a different color when the target is reached:
                const color = found ? "rgb(255, 255, 0)" : "rgb(0, 0, 255)";
                fillTile(neighbor, color); // Avoid code repetition: use reusable function
            }, 0 + timer * 100); // Use a timeout that is relevant for the user experience
            if (found) return true;
        }
    }
}

// Utility function to verify whether coordinates are valid
const validCoordinate = ({xPos, yPos}) =>
    xPos >= 0 && xPos * colWidth < canvasWidth && yPos >= 0 && yPos * colWidth < canvasWidth;

// Function to fill a tile, so to avoid code repetition
function fillTile(tile, color) {
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(tile.xPos * colWidth, tile.yPos * colWidth, colWidth, colWidth);
}

function handleClick(event) {
    let xPos = event.offsetX;
    let yPos = event.offsetY;
    let col = Math.floor(xPos / colWidth);
    let row = Math.floor(yPos / colWidth);

    if (selectingStart) {
        startNode = createCoordinate(col, row);
        fillTile(startNode, "rgb(0, 255, 0)"); // Avoid code repetition: use reusable function
        selectingStart = false;
    } else if (selectingEnd) {
        endNode = createCoordinate(col, row);
        fillTile(endNode, "rgb(255, 0, 0)"); // Avoid code repetition: use reusable function
        selectingEnd = false;
        dijkstra(startNode, endNode);
        canvas.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
    }
}

// Rest of the code to make the snippet runnable
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
const canvasWidth = canvas.width;
canvas.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
const colWidth = 50;
let selectingStart = true;
let selectingEnd = true;
let startNode, endNode;
const visitedNodes = new Set;

function drawGrid() {
    for (let i = 0; i < canvasWidth; i += colWidth) {
        context.moveTo(0, i);
        context.lineTo(canvasWidth, i);
        context.moveTo(i, 0);
        context.lineTo(i, canvasWidth);
    }
    context.stroke();
}
const createCoordinate = (xPos, yPos) => ({xPos, yPos});
const stringifyCoordinate = ({xPos, yPos}) => JSON.stringify([xPos, yPos]);
const compareCoordinates = (a, b) => stringifyCoordinate(a) === stringifyCoordinate(b);

drawGrid();
```

```html
<canvas width="800" height="600"></canvas>
```

Finally, you could have a look at *promisifying* `setTimeout` so that you can have the benefit of `async` and `await`. This way you can make `dijkstra` return a promise that resolves when the animation has been completed.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful reply. I had originally set the timing to 0 thinking that the time delays were causing the effect but still had the issue persist. Following your strategy of adding the constant variable in the correct scope fixed my issue. So just to clarify I should always use a locally scoped variable that don't dynamically change to avoid these closure issues.